# Is there a QGIS plugin that allows users to interface with a PHP form page?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, php

I've been looking for several days for a QGIS plugin that allows users to interface with a PHP form page.

Does anyone know something that works in this way?

Comment: Why should there be? For what purpose? Give us some more info here...

Comment: Hi, I need it to interface Qgis with a PHP page that send/receive datas from an external database